# Thermal Printing using ZJIANG ZJ5890T

Tags: thermal-printer, escpos

Can someone help me with thermal printing. So I had successfully generate QR Code and print the QR Code via USB thermal printer. But all I want is printing another text beside the QR Code. I use the python-escpos library from github.

Here is my code:

```
from escpos import *
import qrcode
import sys

from PIL import Image
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=8,
    border=1,
)
#get the string from sys.argv to store in QR Code
list = sys.argv 
y=0;
#define the printer
E = printer.Usb(0x0416,0xaabb) 

for x in list:
        #to ignore some args
        if(y!=0): 
                #make the QR Code
                qr.clear()
                qr.add_data(x)
                qr.make()

                #generating QR Code
                im = qr.make_image() 
                #Saving the QR Code to current path
                im.save(str(x)+'.png') 
                #printing the QR Code
                E.image(str(x)+'.png') 
        else:
                y=y+1
```

Comment: Also, I use for Raspberry Pi B to handle the python

Comment: One more thing, I was unable to print an image that larger than 255ppx: